# How to put value in a textbox from a public static void

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I'm really new to C# and so I have a question: I have a `public static void` method and I want to do stuff within it and then put a value to an datagridview how can I connect to that item on the form?

I use `public static void` because I call this from an other form, on that form I load a file end write it to the database and I want to reload instantly only the datagridview of form1.

It doesn't recognize "Grid_Tek" not even when I put the formname before it like `form1.Grid_Tek`

```
public static void renew()
{ 
    SqlConnection con_tek = new SqlConnection("blablabla:");
    DataTable tb_tek = new DataTable();

    SqlDataAdapter da_tek = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM file WHERE code ='" + code + "'   ORDER BY date  desc", con_tek);

    da_tek.Fill(tb_tek);

    Grid_Tek.DataSource = "";
    Grid_Tek.DataSource = tb_tek;
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Meh, this happens when people start with all those new and shiny books and then it is database this, forms that, tables there... Nemesis417, you need first grasp basics of C# and concepts of memory layout, static sharing, etc first.
Console App first. Learn to crawl, then walk, then fly. Space Flight, databases, forms interactions is really last thing to do :)...

Answer (score 0):

A “static” method is not going to have access to the “outside” world. Remove the “static” keyword from the method definition and then the method “will” see the `Grid_Tek` object.

When you state that… *“I use public static void because I call this from an other form…”* ? Does this other form ALSO contain an object called `Grid_Tek`?

The method `renew` looks like it is simply reading from the database and filling a `DataTable` based on the given `code`, then sets that `DataTable` as a `DataSource` to an object named `Grid_Tek`.

This method is doing “too many things.” By assigning the `DataTable` to an object “inside” the method means that this method will ONLY work if “some” object is passed in such that we can assign its data source to the `DataTable` read from the DB.

IMHO, this method should NOT assign the `DataTable` as a `DataSource` to some given object. It should not care about what object “needs” the `DataTable` the method simply “returns” the `DataTable` and lets the caller assign the “returned” `DataTable` to the `DataSource` of its choice.

With the `DataSource` assignment moved out of the method, then it really does only ONE (1) thing. It returns a `DataTable` given the `code.` Now all forms can call this method and you wont have the conflicts you are experiencing now since the assignment of the table is left to the caller.

Also, since multiple “forms” may call this method, it makes no sense to put the method “in” one of the forms. I suggest creating a static “Utility” class where all forms can call the method and remove any ambiguity. Below are the changes described above.

```
public static class Utilities {
  public static DataTable renew(string code) { 
    SqlConnection con_tek = new SqlConnection("blablabla:");
    DataTable tb_tek = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da_tek = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM file WHERE code ='" + code + "' ORDER BY date  desc", con_tek);
    da_tek.Fill(tb_tek);
    return tb_tek;
  }
}
```

Now, in the first form you can call it like…

```
form1.Grid_Tek.DataSource = Utilities.renew(code);
```

In the second form…

```
form2.SomeDifferentGrid.DataSource = Utilities.renew(code);
```

I hope that makes sense.

Lastly, you should review/research “marc_s” comment about SQL Injection. In almost all environments, using parameterized queries will be required. So, you might want to learn how to properly pass parameters to an SQL query string.

Comment: realy thanks for the answer , this works for me with the exception of that i had to add form1 on form2  `Frorm1.Grid_Tek.DataSource = form1.utilities.renew(code)` but this do the trick of refreshing only the grid on form1.

Comment: @nemesis417 … From the statement… `form1.utilities.renew(code)` …. means you have put the `Utilities` code “inside” the `Form1` Class! … Do not do this, make a NEW “STATIC” Class called `Utilities` in its own file. This may explain why… _”this works for me with the exception of that i had to add form1 on form2”_